# Can AnkhSVN be installed on an Express edition of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express, ankhsvn

Can AnkhSVN be installed on an Express edition of Visual Studio?

Comment: Team Foundation Server 2012 Express? http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/esn/products/visual-studio-team-foundation-server-express#product-express-tfs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, because the Express editions explicitly do not allow plugins.  See also [AnkhSVN's FAQ](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/wiki/Faq/#head-5cfda3c01b2ff5bab6b3742c33ced4abe1426eb2):

> ### Does it work with the Visual Studio 2005 / 2008 / 2010 Express versions?
>
> No, and it might never do so. The current position from Microsoft is that these SKUs will not support addins.

That being said, there's nothing stopping you from using any other source control tool outside of Visual Studio.  It's really not that painful to drop back to a command line for a commit.

Comment: (And for some interesting reading about this fact: http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2007/05/30/microsoft-vs-testdriven-net-express.aspx)

Comment: It is painful, though, to drop down to command line for a rename, and then have to adjust the solution file. That's really the value of AnkhSVN for me.

Answer (score 4):

> It's really not that painful to drop back to a command line for a commit.

On Windows you don't really have to fall back to command line. Most people (including me) don't like the idea to go back to 1989 on MS operating systems ;) There is a pretty nice tool called [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) that integrates into the file explorer.

We use this combination of VS Express and [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) in our company. It works pretty well for us. Maybe you can have a different experience on non Windows platforms.

Comment: I believe the use of a _command line_ is what differentiates a _techie_ from a _non techie_.

Comment: @AlanGee: It's nerdy vs non-nerdy. Techies often like GUIs (like myself).